# Default action when user completes text input on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a simple Windows Phone 8 app and I have the keyboard show up correctly using the Url InputScope. At the bottom right corner of the soft keyboard (SIP) a right arrow is displayed.

How do I detect that the user clicks that button?

I've tried the KeyUp-event, but the Key class is not defined so I can't compare e.Key with Key.ENTER - and I also have a feeling that it isn't correct to check the key code, semantically speaking. I'd rather find some "onSubmit" event like in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by first adding "using System.Windows.Input;" to the top of my .cs file. After that the Key class became available.

XAML:

```
<TextBox KeyUp="txtUrl_KeyUp" x:Name="txtUrl" InputScope="Url"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ManipulationCompleted="txtUrl_ManipulationCompleted" Margin="0,127,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
```

C#:

```
private void txtUrl_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter)) {
        navigateTo(txtUrl.Text);
        webBrowser.focus(); // Hides the input box
    }
}
```